# Can Oracle databases start automatically when Windows machine is booted/rebooted?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

In one of my client machines every time Windows starts we have to start the Oracle database manually.
Is there a solution/ command to start the database automatically when the machine is started/restarted?

Comment: Are you using grid infrastructure? if you are then your database should be registered with Oracle Restart which will automatically start database and its dependent components upon system reboot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Follow the below steps to get it done:**

- Open the registry with regedit.  Always back up the registry before
  making changes. Navigate to the key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\oracle_home_name`.

  **There will be a key called:**

  `ORA_SID_AUTOSTART`.  SID is your database SID.
- This key should be set to `TRUE`. If not the server starts but does
  not start the database.  There is also an `ORA_SID_SHUTDOWN` which you 
  want to be `TRUE` so that if the server is shut down the service will 
  shutdown the database.
- If you want to manually start the database set `ORA_SID_AUTOSTART` to
  `FALSE`.  The service will start but not the database.

Comment: ORA_SID_AUTOSTART is already set to     TRUE.still facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

on Windows system you have to use oradim.exe to admnister the Oracle instance behavior.
This is the documentation:
[Using ORADIM to Administer an Oracle Database Instance](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/win.102/b14304/create.htm#NTQRF352)

You have to check:

- if the Windows service exists (if not create it with oradim);
- how it is configured (using oradim)